# stop refreshing all queries at once in excel using macro

Tags: excel, vba

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am refreshing all queries in the workbook after some specific interval using
this macro.

```
Sub macro_t()

    
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
   interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:015")
  Application.OnTime interval, "macro_t"

End Sub
```

I want macro which will stop refreshing queries.
something like

```
stoprefreshall
```

how can I do it?

**edit**
the way i solve the issue is, stopping refresh of each sheet one by one
and then again run macro.

I want to stop refreshing all the sheets in single step, using macro

[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of trial and error
and finally this worked.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
 


With Sheets("r1").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable
 If .Refreshing Then .CancelRefresh
End With

 
 
  With Sheets("r2").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable
 If .Refreshing Then .CancelRefresh
End With


 With Sheets("r3").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable
 If .Refreshing Then .CancelRefresh
End With


 With Sheets("s1").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable
 If .Refreshing Then .CancelRefresh
End With


 With Sheets("s2").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable
 If .Refreshing Then .CancelRefresh
End With


 With Sheets("s3").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable
 If .Refreshing Then .CancelRefresh
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Odd, this is certainly what's in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.cancelrefresh), but it doesn't work for me, even with `BackgroundQuery:=False`. The query `.Refreshing` incorrectly reports as `False` and forcing `.CancelRefresh` just returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare a boolean type variable outside of procedure. And create a macro which will set that boolean variable to false and then macro will not run after run the `StopMacro(). Try below codes.

```
Public Times As Boolean

Sub start()
    Range("E3").Value = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    Times = True
    run
End Sub

Sub run()
    If Not Times Then Exit Sub
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Run"
    Range("E3").Value = Range("E3").Value + TimeValue("00:00:01")
End Sub

Sub StopMacro()
    Times = False
End Sub
```

For better visualization see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: stopping macro doesnt solve the issue, i need to manually stop refreshing each table one by one, is there any way i can do this using macro. i mean stop refreshing particular sheet using macro,    i have added screenshot in the question